# How do I generate a scaffold for a Sencha Touch 2.x app?

Tags: sencha-touch, extjs, sencha-touch-2

I installed the ST SDK tools, and when I do 'sencha' at the command line I see this:

```
$ sencha
Sencha Command v2.0.0 Developer Preview
Copyright (c) 2011 Sencha Inc.


usage: sencha COMMAND [ARGS]


The available commands are:
   build            build a JSB project
   create bootstrapdata        generate boostrap data
   create jsb            generate a minimal JSB project for an app
   create manifest        generate classes manifest
   package            package your Touch web app into a native bundle
   slice theme            slice a custom theme's images for IE


See 'sencha help COMMAND' for more information on a specific command.
```

But when I try 'create bootstrapdata' it is asking me for all sorts of options.

```
$ sencha create bootstrapdata
usage: sencha create bootstrapdata [OPTIONS...]


 COMMAND: Generate Bootstrap Data


 DESCRIPTION:


   Generate boostrap data 
 OPTIONS:


 --core[=]value, -c[=]value (required)
   The list of all core package names, comma-separated, for example: 
   "foundation,core,dom" 


 --ignore[=][value], -i[=][value]
   The list of items to be ignored, comma-separated 


 --jsb[=]value, -j[=]value (required)
   The path to the framework's jsb3 file 


 --output[=]value, -o[=]value (required)
   The file path to write bootstrap data to 


 --output-release[=][value], -r[=][value]
   The file path to write bootstrap data-release to 


 --platform[=]value, -p[=]value (required)
   The path to platform source directory 


 --src[=]value, -s[=]value (required)
   The path to the framework's source directory
```

How do I use one command at the command-line, without needing filepaths and other 'required' options, to generate a 'basic Hello World' ST2.x app?

Thanks.

Edit1: Btw, What I am trying to do is what Tommy Maintz did in his presentation on ST1.x at [ST 2010 Conference](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/video/17705448).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sencha generate does not exist for Sencha Touch 2 at this time. Sencha have plans to release an update for it at some point in the future, after ST2 has been released.

`sencha create bootstrapdata` is used when compiling your application into one JS file. You can find out more information about this [here](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/guide/building).

I also recommend you to ask questions over on the [Sencha Touch Forums](http://www.sencha.com/forum/forumdisplay.php?89-Sencha-Touch-2.x-Forums), which is extremely active.

Comment: I actually did ask over there, but I didn't get a proper response so I came here - http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?180456-How-do-I-generate-a-scaffold-for-an-ST-2.x-app&p=732835&posted=1#post732835

Comment: No worries. Happens to the best of us.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do just that then go here http://sencha.com/x/6p and download the code from the presentation. In there you will find folder Command in the lib folder. While in that folder execute the following command:

```
./sencha generate app 'MyApp'
```

Note the `./`

Comment: This will generate files for Sencha Touch 1.x, not 2.x.

Comment: Yes, of course. I already up-voted your answer. I'm just giving instructions how to repeat the steps he saw Tommy Maintz did.